# wget download runs ins cmd but not in task scheduler

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks, wget

I want to download big files to my windows 2008 R2 webserver. I can run wget in the CMD without any problems an it is downloading the complete file. But if I enter the script to the task scheduler  the download gets interupted after an irregular amount of downloaded MB.

This is what I entered in the Task Scheduler:

1. Execute with highest priviliges (checked)
2. Aktions

Programm:
C:\webserver\wget\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe

Arguments:
-c --no-check-certificate --no-parent --accept "foo" --no-directories --recursive -P C:/downloadpath/ --http-user=x --http-password=y https://someurl.com/

Start in:
(left blank)

---> Since it is completing in cmd but not in the Task Scheduler I asume it might be related to any user account permitions. Any one an idea?

Comment: Does the Task Scheduler provide some error or success constants? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What does "gets interrupted" mean? Any error message?

Comment: There is no error message in the history of the task. The task is still aktiv in the task scheduler (so displayed as running) but the the file size of the downloaded file isnt increasing anymore after a while so by "gets interupted" I ment that the file size is no longer increasing